# cv2.imshow() giving black screen

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I'm converting a image (numpy array) into a string. Then I'm converting this string back to a numpy array of the original dimensions. Hence both the numpy arrays are equal- infact `numpy.array_equals()` also returns `True` for the arrays being equal.

When I call `cv2.imshow()` on the original numpy array, it prints the image. But when I call `cv2.imshow()` on the new numpy array, I get only a black screen.

Why is this happening? Both the numpy arrays are equal, so I should get the same output right?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

frame = cv2.imread( '/home/nirvan/img_two.png' , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
string = ' '.join(map(str,frame.flatten().tolist()))

frameCopy = frame.copy()

x = frame.shape[0]
y = frame.shape[1]

frame = string.strip()
temp = [ int(t) for t in frame.split(' ')]
temp = np.array(temp)
temp = temp.reshape( (x,y) )

print( np.array_equal(frameCopy , temp) )

#gives black screen
cv2.imshow('l' , np.array(temp) )

#gives proper image
#cv2.imshow('l' , np.array(frameCopy) )

cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your arrays i.e. your frames are equal, but the data types are not. Your `temp` array is of type `int64` while `imshow` expects `uint8`. The following will fix your script:

```
cv2.imshow('l' , np.array(temp, dtype = np.uint8 ) )
```

Answer (score 5):

searching for  imshow() giving black screen led me to this post but I am on windows 11
in my case, I was actually missing the waitKey command  which is required  to show image otherwise no errors and black screen

```
 # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Thx! 
I was trying to show an image while debugging, on halt on breakpoint, in pycharm debugger console, but was getting a black image.
This solved it for me.